# Doing inference with two Tensorflow models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have inference application. The application used two inference models.

The two models and restored to two different graphs and run in two different sessions.

Detection inference produced position of object and second inference recognize the separate objects inside the crop image.

The error is happening at second inference.

The error is

```
2019-06-17 22:08:34.454728: F tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.cc: 44]Check failed:NDIMS==dims() (2 vs. 3)Asking for tensor of 2 dimensions from a tensor of 3 dimensions
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The error is at

```
b, s, c = sess.run([self.box, self.score, self.cls], feed_dict={self.image_tensor: image_data})
```

What could be wrong? My tensorflow is 1.9.

The whole code is as follow.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time


class Recognition:
   def __init__(self):
      self.reg_graph = tf.Graph()
      with self.reg_graph.as_default():
          od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
          with tf.gfile.GFile("recognition_tf_model/frozen_model.pb", 'rb') as fid:
             serialized_graph = fid.read()
             od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
             tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
             self.image_tensor = self.reg_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
             self.box = self.reg_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
             self.score = self.reg_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
             self.cls = self.reg_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

   def infer(self, crop, frame, w, h):
      with tf.Session(graph=self.reg_graph) as sess:
         image = cv2.resize(crop,(512,300))
         image_data = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0).astype(np.uint8)
         b, s, c = sess.run([self.box, self.score, self.cls], feed_dict={self.image_tensor: image_data})
         if(len(b)==0 or len(s)==0 or len(c)==0):
            return
         boxes = b[0]
         conf = s[0]
         clses = c[0]
         for i in (range(len(boxes))):
            bx = boxes[i]
            if conf[i] < 0.5:
              continue
            p1 = (int(w * bx[1]), int(h * bx[0]))
            p2 = (int(w * bx[3]) ,int(h * bx[2]))
            cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (0,255,0))
      cv2.imshow("Numplate recognition", frame)
      cv2.waitKey(1)

def main():
   dr=Recognition()
   vidoe_path = "../../../Data/plates/IMG_5715.MOV"
   det_graph = tf.Graph()
   with det_graph.as_default():
      with tf.Session(graph=det_graph) as sess:
         graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
         with tf.gfile.GFile("detection_tf_model/frozen_model.pb", 'rb') as fid:
            serialized_graph = fid.read()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
            image_tensor = det_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
            box = det_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
            score = det_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
            cls = det_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
         cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vidoe_path)
         width = cap.get(3)  # float
         height = cap.get(4) # float
         while True:
           fps_time=time.time()
           ret, frame = cap.read()
           if(ret==0):
             break
           image = cv2.resize(frame,(300,300))
           image_data = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0).astype(np.uint8)
           b, s, c = sess.run([box, score, cls], {image_tensor: image_data})
           if(len(b)==0 or len(s)==0 or len(c)==0):
              continue
           boxes = b[0]
           conf = s[0]
           clses = c[0]
           #writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('debug', sess.graph)
           for i in (range(5)):
              bx = boxes[i]
              if conf[i] < 0.5:
                  continue
              p1 = (int(width * bx[1]), int(height * bx[0]))
              p2 = (int(width * bx[3]) ,int(height * bx[2]))
              cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (0,255,0))
              dr.infer(frame[p1[1]:p2[1], p1[0]:p2[0]], frame, width, height)
           print('FPS: %f' % (1.0/(time.time() - fps_time)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TX2 provides Tensorflow1.9. Tensorflow1.9 has this issue. Now build Tensorflow1.12 from source and the issue was solved.